# How to get Capacitor URL Scheme params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to get URL Schemes params in my Capacitor Ionic+React app.
I need something like this:

After typing myAppURLScheme://myParam='param' in my browser I would like to read it in someway like this

```
const myParam = getParamsWithCapacitor('myParam');
```

Is there any native way or a package I may use?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need use capacitor. the Angular Route
Like this

```
   constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) {}

 

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.name = params['name'];
  });
}
```